# Get number of rows that match certain conditions and add to column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

So I have the following data table:

```
Name | Addr   | Age
-------------------
Bill | 2112 W | 17
Barb | 2112 W | 16
Rick | 3445 E | 16
Chad | 2112 W | 5
Ruth | 5567 S | 4
Mick | 3445 E | 17
Hank | 3445 E | 1
Lace | 1111 S | 16
Nick | 2112 W | 4
```

I want to add a calculated column that checks to see if the number of rows that meet the following criteria is greater than two: all the rows where the address is the same AND the age is >15, therefore the new table would be:

```
Name | Addr   | Age | Count
---------------------------
Bill | 2112 W | 17  | TRUE    #There are two people at addr 2112 W over 15, so True
Barb | 2112 W | 16  | TRUE    #There are two people at addr 2112 W over 15, so True
Rick | 3445 E | 16  | TRUE    #There are two people at addr 3445 E over 15, so True
Chad | 2112 W | 5   | TRUE    #There are two people at addr 2112 W over 15, so True
Ruth | 5567 S | 4   | FALSE   #No one at 5567 S is over 15, so False
Mick | 3445 E | 17  | TRUE    #There are two people at addr 3445 E over 15, so True
Hank | 3445 E | 1   | TRUE    #There are two people at addr 3445 E over 15, so True
Lace | 1111 S | 16  | FALSE   #Only one person over 15 is at addr 1111 S, so False
Nick | 5567 S | 16   | FALSE  #Two people live at addr, but only one of them is over 15 so False
```

This is the solution that I'm currently trying:

dat$COUNT<- Map(function(x) nrow(dat[dat$ADDR== x & dat$ADDR > 15]) >= 2, dat$ADDR)

But this doesn't seem to be working correctly, and goes extremely slow with large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
var$Count <- ifelse(var$Age>=15,"| TRUE","| FALSE")
var %>% group_by(Addr)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
* <fct> <int> <fct> <fct> <int> <chr>  
1 |      2112 W     |        17 | TRUE 
2 |      2112 W     |        16 | TRUE 
3 |      3445 E     |        16 | TRUE 
4 |      2112 W     |         5 | FALSE
5 |      5567 S     |         4 | FALSE
6 |      3445 E     |        17 | TRUE 
7 |      3445 E     |         1 | FALSE
8 |      1111 S     |        16 | TRUE
```

Comment: @akrun, apologies to tag you here, could you please suggest how could I skip headers here? I am seeing headers are coming like `Name     X. Addr  X..1    Age Count` in output, will be grateful to you if you could guide and edit my answer or I could edit it, thanks.

Comment: Not, sure, I understand your query.  How did you created the dataset?

Comment: You don't need the quoted TRUE, FALSE and also the ifelse, if would be just `var$Age>=15`

Comment: The description in the OP's post is a bit unclear.  May be you need `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, Count :=  .N >= 2 & any(Age > 15), .(Addr)]`

Comment: @Santi, it looks exactly same as per your shown output only please do let me know where is the problem?

Comment: Hello. It is not the same as the chart I posted, rows 4 7 and 8 are different than what I posted. It looks like what you're doing is checking to see if the current row's age is over 15. What I was trying to accomplish is see if there are two or more people at the given address over 15. So for example, in row 4 that you provided it's false when it should be true. Even though the age of #4 isn't over 15, rows 1 and 2 share the same addr and they are both over 15, therefore #4 would also be true.

Comment: @akrun your answer was the solution, and it worked significantly faster. thanks!

Comment: @Santi It assigns the column by reference and it is faster

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(Addr) %>%
    mutate(count = n() > 1)
## A tibble: 8 x 4
## Groups:   Addr [4]
#  Name  Addr     Age count
#  <fct> <fct>  <int> <lgl>
#1 Bill  2112 W    17 TRUE
#2 Barb  2112 W    16 TRUE
#3 Rick  3445 E    16 TRUE
#4 Chad  2112 W     5 TRUE
#5 Ruth  5567 S     4 FALSE
#6 Mick  3445 E    17 TRUE
#7 Hank  3445 E     1 TRUE
#8 Lace  1111 S    16 FALSE
```

Or in base R using `ave`

```
df$count <- as.logical(ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$Addr, FUN = function(x) sum(x) > 1))
df
#  Name   Addr Age count
#1 Bill 2112 W  17  TRUE
#2 Barb 2112 W  16  TRUE
#3 Rick 3445 E  16  TRUE
#4 Chad 2112 W   5  TRUE
#5 Ruth 5567 S   4 FALSE
#6 Mick 3445 E  17  TRUE
#7 Hank 3445 E   1  TRUE
#8 Lace 1111 S  16 FALSE
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Name  Addr    Age
Bill  '2112 W'  17
Barb  '2112 W'  16
Rick  '3445 E'  16
Chad  '2112 W'  5
Ruth  '5567 S'  4
Mick  '3445 E'  17
Hank  '3445 E'  1
Lace  '1111 S'  16", header = T)
```

---

### Update

With your updated sample data and the requirement that `Age > 15`

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Name  Addr    Age
Bill  '2112 W'  17
Barb  '2112 W'  16
Rick  '3445 E'  16
Chad  '2112 W'  5
Ruth  '5567 S'  4
Mick  '3445 E'  17
Hank  '3445 E'  1
Lace  '1111 S'  16
Nick  '2112 W'  4", header = T)


df %>%
    group_by(Addr) %>%
    mutate(count = n() > 1 & Age > 15)
## A tibble: 9 x 4
## Groups:   Addr [4]
#  Name  Addr     Age count
#  <fct> <fct>  <int> <lgl>
#1 Bill  2112 W    17 TRUE
#2 Barb  2112 W    16 TRUE
#3 Rick  3445 E    16 TRUE
#4 Chad  2112 W     5 FALSE
#5 Ruth  5567 S     4 FALSE
#6 Mick  3445 E    17 TRUE
#7 Hank  3445 E     1 FALSE
#8 Lace  1111 S    16 FALSE
#9 Nick  2112 W     4 FALSE
```

Comment: I think what this is checking is to see if there are two people or more at the address, not if there are two people over the age of 15 at the address. The output with this data set is the same, but if I were to add a row that says 'Nick' ' 5567 S' '5' all of a sudden #4 and the new row would be true. I'll add this row to highlight that since your answer will give a correct output for this specific dataset

Comment: @Santi I've updated my answer; please take a look. I'm not sure why Hank should get flagged as `TRUE` because `Age < 15 though.

Answer (score 0):

@akrun got the answer below

[Get number of rows that match certain conditions and add to column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254984/get-number-of-rows-that-match-certain-conditions-and-add-to-column-in-r/51268578#comment89491148_51255269)